# Get updated mesh data after editing

Tags: python, scripting, mesh, transforms

I converted a curve to a mesh, and got the mesh data with:

```
   mesh = bpy.context.object.data
```

This mesh had 47 vertices at this point. Then , I extruded the mesh (via script) along Z, and got 47 new vertices because of that (total 94)

However, this new addition is not reflected in my mesh data now. If I now perform some new operations using `mesh.vertices` , it only affects the older vertices and doesn't affect the new ones.

How should I go about this?

Comment: I did a quick test and it looks like you have to leave edit mode to get updated object data.